# Using Redirects in GAE

Tags: google-app-engine, go

I am fairly new to Go, and I am trying to make a few apps for GAE. I couldn't find anyone with the same problem as me so I thought I would ask here!

Basically, I am creating a program that will take a random url from an array and redirect the user.

The problem that arises is that on every computer I try it on, it will send a different video, but it will always send the same video to that person.

If anyone has any insight into this it would be greatly appreciated!

```
    package randvid

    import (
        "net/http"
        "math/rand"
        "time"
    )

    func RandLink() string{
      VideoList := []string{
        ...
      }
      r := rand.New(rand.NewSource(time.Now().UTC().UnixNano()))
      vid := r.Intn(len(VideoList)) + 1;
      return VideoList[vid]
    }

    func redirectHandler(path string) func(http.ResponseWriter, *http.Request) {
      return func (w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        http.Redirect(w, r, path, http.StatusMovedPermanently)
      }
    }

    func init() {
      http.HandleFunc("/", redirectHandler(RandLink()))
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your clients are probably caching the 301 response [as allowed by RFC 2616](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-10.3.2).

Change the response status code to 302, [http.StatusFound](https://godoc.org/net/http#StatusFound).